# 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python, subprocess, text-to-speech, rasa

**I copy code from a tutorial and run as below, but I have an error from**

```
subprocess.call(['mpg321', "welcome.mp3", '--play-and-exit'])

import subprocess

from gtts import gTTS

mytext = 'Welcome to Innovate Yourself!'

language = 'en'

myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language)

myobj.save("welcome.mp3")

subprocess.call(['mpg321', "welcome.mp3", '--play-and-exit'])
```

**the error like this**

```
 File "text_to_speech.py", line 12
    subprocess.call(["vlc","C:\Users\Alexp\rasatest\actions\welcome.mp3","--play-and-exit"])
                          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

(rasatest) C:\Users\Alexp\rasatest\actions>python text_to_speech.py
  File "text_to_speech.py", line 13
    subprocess.call(["vlc","C:\Users\Alexp\rasatest\actions\welcome.mp3","--play-and-exit"])
                          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

**how can I solve this error?**

Comment: ``\U`` marks the start of a unicode escape. Use raw strings or forward slashes.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi we really need a canonical dupe for these questions, it's like the third one today.

Comment: @MattDMo Do you have a better one in mind? I don't use Windows myself anymore, but it seems to be on point.